# How to read a posted file in C# Discord.net?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I would like to make my `discord.net` bot read a file that is posted in the chat. So far I can't seem to find an answer for this in C#.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer I was looking for was the fact that I can access a user's message and pretty much any details about it using `Context.Message` especially in a class that inherits from `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>`. Like this, I can use the `System.Net` module to download the contents of the attachment from the URL and do whatever I wanted with it.

Here is a sample command that implements the above. Side note: it does not implement any security measures for simplicity.

```
[Command("printFile")]
public async Task PrintFile()
{
    var attachments = Context.Message.Attachments;

    // Create a new WebClient instance.
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

    string file = attachments.ElementAt(0).Filename;
    string url = attachments.ElementAt(0).Url;

    // Download the resource and load the bytes into a buffer.
    byte[] buffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(url);

    // Encode the buffer into UTF-8
    string download = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

    Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");

    // Place the contents as a message because the method said it should.
    await ReplyAsync("Received attachment!\n\n" + download);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the async nature of the discord bot API and it's extensive use of tasks might I suggest that you use HttpClient instead and perform the operation asynchronously ...

```
public class DebugModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("read")]
    [Summary("Reads the contents of a dropped file.")]
    public async Task Read() {
        using(var client = new HttpClient())
            await ReplyAsync(await client.GetStringAsync(Context.Message.Attachments.First().Url));
    }
}
```

Since i have configured my bot like many others to use ! as a prefix the usage here is simple ...

drop file on to channel
type comment as "!read"
This instructs the bot to then reply with the contents of the uploaded file in an async manner.